# Blender is rendering only part of the tiles

Tags: rendering, error

this is my first question here.
My scene is rendering with some artifacts in the viewport:

[image: Viewport render with artifacts]

And when I hit render animation or render image it only renders part of the tile and stops about 1/5th from the top with some different artifacts:

[image: Whole image rendered (even the black strip on top)]

When I try to render with the CPU I don't even get an image, just a black screen

Here's a link to download my project:
[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16HfVhozDFIvSOd_rgbWEMymq5euV3snO/view?usp=drive_link)

Please, I need to render this for the weekend, I'm grateful for any help

Comment: Attempting to open the file causes Blender to crash...

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   Blender [16618]

Comment: The artifacts in the viewport come from the "Neblina" object. It has a very low resolution, if you put a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on it, the artifacts disappear but it also gets a lot, lot darker - you should multiply the density (the output of the _Color Ramp_ in the "Neblina" material) with a very low value. For the rendering: everything works fine here, I cannot reproduce the issue. Might be hardware problems. @NascentSpace Which Blender version are you using?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Blender 2.92 on an old macbook, so should probably take my experience with a grain of salt.

Comment: @NascentSpace Blend file says it's version 3.06, so yeah there are compatibility issues between 2.9x and 3.x files, the older program versions cannot read all from newer Blender files.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using 3.6.4. @GordonBrinkmann, It was indeed the Neblina object, after I hid it from render everything worked fine, so I just rendered without it